# Access: Updating end of day Share values from Yahoo finance

Tags: ms-access, vba, yahoo-finance

am about to make an addition to my database that might make life much easier for users that are not normally accustomed to using it.

I have a table in my database; which holds Historical_stock_data and Historical_currency_data (Values to convert Share Price into dollars) in the other table. Each of them have basically got four & three columns (StockCode, Dates, SharePrice, Volume) and (CurrencyCode, Dates, Rates) respectively.

Now at the end of each trading day; I need to update the both tables. There around 200 companies in the database; and currently I basically have a portfolio in Yahoo finance holding all 200 companies which I download into Excel and edit so it matches the columns; and then manually update the database by adding to the table. (I can use the transfer spreadsheet method as well to do this but I ran into a problem once with it so do it manually now; my coding skills are not the greatest)

The currency prices, since there are only around 6 currencies in the database to dollars; I update them manually; this is not an issue at the moment; but if more companies from different countries are included than it would be easier; and besides it is always better to automate things; so was wondering if this was possible as well.

So if there was a way to update these values directly into Access at the end of each day without having to bother with Excel; that would be great. If there is then if I'm shown an example of what sort of code to use with just one example; I should be able to finish it.

Comment: It should be possible, what page in Yahoo finance?

Answer (score 0):

Search on "yahoo stock price excel" and you should find lots of sample code.  Then convert the code to using recordsets/tables instead of cells and you're done.